# WKWebView load html from document directory don't work on device

Tags: html, ios, swift, ios11, wkwebview

So, I have downloaded folder with html file.

[folders struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlkyu.png)

I tried to open it in WKWebView.

```
let documentsUrl = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let url = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("\(model.sourceFileId)/index.html") 
self.webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
```

It works fine on simulator

[screenshot from simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Zh6.png)

but not on device

[screenshot from device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxEAF.png)

Looks like it's just can't open css and images files. But why? How can I fix this?

Comment: I bet it has something to do with the paths in the html. Might not be able to find the css and image files.

Comment: @Dima Did you fixed this?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the files into `NSTemporaryDirectory()` and open the file URL, and it works. I've wrote my code in Objective-C style.

```
NSString *basePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dirName"];
NSString *indexHtmlPath = [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"index.html"];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:indexHtmlPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:basePath];
[self.wkWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift version of using temp directory to save and open documents.

```
            let docData = data as NSData
            let tempDirectory = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
            let tmpURL = tempDirectory.appendingPathComponent(response?.suggestedFilename ?? "fileName.pdf")
            do {
                try data.write(to: self.tmpURL! )
            } catch {
                self.showError()
                return
            }
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: self.tmpURL!.path){
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.webView.loadFileURL(self.tmpURL!, allowingReadAccessTo: self.tmpURL!)
                }
            }
            else{
                self.showError()
            }
```